# Name of list doesn't update on Quick Launch bar

Tags: list

I've been having a problem with the name of a list displaying incorrectly on the Quick Launch bar.  I changed the name of the list using the list settings, but the original name of the list still appears on the Quick Launch, even though everywhere else it shows the new name.

Also, not sure if these observations are connected, but I also noticed that when I look at the file structure of my site in Windows Explorer, the folder names don't update in this view either and if I try to change the folder names in Explorer, then Explorer crashes.  Additionally, I have a task list whose name I changed, and even though this list shows correctly on the Quick Launch, when I assign the task, the email that gets sent out gives the old name of the folder...

Any ideas?

Jay

Answer (score 1):

As above, update it from the site settings. When you change the list name it wont update the url or the folder name in explorer.

Changing the name of a folder in explorer does not usally crash it, and the URL will also update in sharepoint. However its not really the way to go about doing it. Have you tried changing it in sharepoint designer ?

Answer (score 0):

Go into Site Settings and click either the Quick Launch or Navigation link to update the value.